# How to hide query strings from url?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, query-string

So my links goes like this:
    http://abcdefgh.com/index?site=XXXX 
    http://abcdefgh.com/index?category=YYYY
    http://abcdefgh.com/index?category=YYYY&site=XXXX
I want to hide the query strings and the user should view the links this:
    http://abcdefgh.com/index/site/XXXX 
    http://abcdefgh.com/index/category/YYYY
    http://abcdefgh.com/index/category/YYYY/site/XXXX
I did try all the answers from previous questions on the same topic but it wouldn't work. Help me with the .htaccess codes

Comment: What did you try and what were the effects?

Comment: You should use mod_rewrite (if you are using apache) (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: @Ivar He tried someone to figure out the codes instead of doing a minimum research. The effects were someone told him he should write in the .htaccess, so he refined his question until someone make the research for him.

Comment: I tried this RewriteRule ^index/(.*)/?$ index?category=$1 [NC,L]<br>

Comment: I used this RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] to hide .php and it works well but I am unable to hide the query strings

Comment: I tried this too RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index?category=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `.htaccess` for your URL http://abcdefgh.com/XXXX

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

## RewriteCond Set here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1    [QSA,L]
```